# Can conductors store charge?

Tags: power-electronics, physics, electrically-conductive

Why are conductors not used to store charge? How does clouds hold such large volume of charges?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This is an Q&A site for electrical engineering design questions so your question is likely to be closed. You might want to ask it on physics.stackexchange.com but you should do a little research first. I suggest you read up about capacitors.

Comment: We should just move everything to the cloud ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charge can be stored in a capacitor, which is a combination of two conductors with something insulating (a dielectric) between them.  Charge accumulates on the conductors, but the energy is actually stored in the dielectric.

Clouds are lots of little conductors (water drops) separated by insulation (the air).  The ground is yet another conductor also insulated from the water drops.

Therefore a cloud as a whole can act as a capacitor to ground and store a lot of charge.  Parts of clouds can also act as capacitors with each other.

Sometimes, strong thermal drafts can move charged particles around in a cloud to build up significant stored charge.  This causes high voltage.  When that voltage gets high enough, it can spark across the air between the two conductors of the capacitor.  That's what we call lightning.  Most lightning is actually between different parts of a cloud, but sometimes it is between a cloud and ground.

Comment: Olin thanks for the answer. I have another question. Does this mean that clouds can't store charge without earth as the capacitor?

Comment: @user: Since lightning can be between different parts of a cloud, clouds can store charge by themselves.  The different parts of the cloud act as the different plates of a capacitor.  When the voltage between these plates gets too high for the air to withstand, lightning occurs between these two parts of the cloud.  Most lightning is actually cloud to cloud, no cloud to ground.

Answer (score 1):

1) Each plate in a capacitor IS a conductor, so conductors do store charge as long as they are separated by an insulator. If there is no insulator, the conductors conduct the separated charge, and it isn't stored any more.

Think of a tank of water, and a pipe as a conductor. If the pipe is blocked (its conductivity is zero, and it is an insulator) the tank can be filled with water. Open the pipe and all the water drains out. Same idea for charge.

2) Clouds are made of "billyuns and billyuns" (to quote Carl Sagan) of water droplets, each of which carries a tiny charge. Each droplet carries a tiny charge but there are lots and lots of them. Enough droplets and you get a big total charge.